# Issue with JAXB and Spring OXM

Tags: xsd, jaxb2, unmarshalling, spring-oxm

I am trying to unmarshall a basic XML document which is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<personnes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="personnes.xsd">
  <personne>
    <prenom>toto</prenom>
    <nom>dupont</nom>
  </personne>
  <personne>
    <prenom>titi</prenom>
    <nom>durand</nom>
  </personne>
  <personne>
    <prenom>tata</prenom>
    <nom>lanvin</nom>
  </personne>
</personnes>
```

The corresponding XSD is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="personnes">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="personne" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="prenom" type="xs:string" />
                            <xs:element name="nom" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I systematically get an UnmarshallingFailureException:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'personne'.]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:664)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:585)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:568)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader.doRead(StaxEventItemReader.java:227)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:85)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:90)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:87)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'personne'.]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshalStaxSource(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:597)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:578)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'personne'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXEventConnector.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXEventConnector.bridge(Unknown Source)
    ... 65 more
```

For your infomation I use Spring OXM.

I strongly suspect this has to do with my XSD schema and possibly namespaces...

Can anyone please help?

**EDIT: Here is the relevant Spring config:**

```
<bean id="personneItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
        <property name="resource" value="classpath:personnes.xml" />
        <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="personne" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>com.docapost.batch.xml.Personnes</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="schema" value="classpath:personnes.xsd" />
    </bean>
```

EDIT 2: exception trace if I comment out the schema validation:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"personne"). Expected elements are <{}personnes>]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:664)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:585)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:568)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader.doRead(StaxEventItemReader.java:227)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:85)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:90)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:87)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"personne"). Expected elements are <{}personnes>]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshalStaxSource(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:597)
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.unmarshal(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:578)
    ... 61 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"personne"). Expected elements are <{}personnes>
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportUnexpectedChildElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext$DefaultRootLoader.childElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXEventConnector.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXEventConnector.bridge(Unknown Source)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"personne"). Expected elements are <{}personnes>
    ... 75 more
```

Comment: Do you see the same exception when you run JAXB outside the Spring environment?

Comment: Good point: it works fine outside of Spring...

Comment: Could you post any Spring related config?

Comment: I finally changed to use an XStreamMarshaller and it works. No luck with the Jaxb2Marshaller...

Comment: Have the same problem. Find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a link been the `personne` element and the `Personne` class.  If you generated your model could you try changing your config to use the context path?

```
<bean id="personneItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="classpath:personnes.xml" />
    <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="personnes" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxb2Marshaller" />
</bean>

<bean id="jaxb2Marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPath" value="ocom.docapost.batch.xml"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: The thing is that the individual items are "personne" tags and not the containing "personnes" tag... See included XML.

Comment: see also [spring batch reference doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#StaxEventItemReader)

Comment: What happens if you comment out `<property name="schema" value="classpath:personnes.xsd" />`.

Comment: I've added the exception stac trace that I get when I comment out the schema property.

Comment: @balteo - I've added an alternate config doc that may work better.